# Masonry.js not taking effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I am simply testing the Masonry.js jQuery plugin/effect on my site, got barely anything on the site apart from the basics, even copied everything from a demo site and it still didn't work. Can't understand why.

It appears as the Masonry jQuery plugin is just not taking any effect or loading, but the page loads the file correctly and the code to call it to action is the Exact same as that on a demo site which it works fine on. As a test I've even got my stylesheet connecting directly from this example site, and all id's and class names are the same.

Live: http://bit.ly/1k7RgDS

Example Site (working fine for this site): http://bit.ly/1kcCmJA

Masonry jQuery Site: http://masonry.desandro.com/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/food/1" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/150/food/10" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/250/food/3" alt="">
        </div>  
        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/food/1" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/150/food/10" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/250/food/3" alt="">
        </div>  
        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/food/1" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/150/food/10" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/250/food/3" alt="">
        </div>  
        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/food/1" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/150/food/10" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/250/food/3" alt="">
        </div>  
        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/200/food/1" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/150/food/10" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="masonryImage">
            <img src="http://lorempixum.com/200/250/food/3" alt="">
        </div>           
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php HTTP_HOST ?>/Scripts/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){

        var $container = $('#container');

        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.masonryImage'
          });
        });

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: The masonry version you are referencing is different from the example site.  This could be the source of the problem.  Instead try using the instructions provided by the masonry jquery site.

Comment: Oh! Perfect, working now. Thank you. As you were first to answer, if you put this as an answer I can vote it up if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

The example site is using a different version of the jQuery masonry plugin.

If you use the syntax provided on the [masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/#jquery) website it will work.

The correct syntax:

```
var $container = $('#container');
// initialize
$container.masonry({
  itemSelector: '.masonryImage'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

going to the page and opening firebug i see:

`$container.imagesLoaded is not a function`

imagesLoaded is not something native to jquery.. you probably need to add this jquery extension to your page

Comment: Different versions of the Masonry plugin is the cause of this. v3.1.4 vs v2.1.02...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're using the latest version of Masonry.  The site you referenced uses an older version of `Masonry` (v2), coming into version 3, Desandro removed `imagesLoaded`, so if you want to use `imagesLoaded`, you'll have to include the JS file from Desandro's page:

http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

In which case your original code will work, however a better way to do it would be

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.masonryImage'
});
$container.imagesLoaded(function () {
    $container.masonry();
});
```

This is probably overkill unless you plan on dynamically loading in new images / don't know the dimensions of your images as Masonry needs those to perform properly.  If that's the case, I'd go with including it.